# Replace object in a list and insert it at the same position

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
// messages:
[
   {id: 2, id_profile: 2, id_groupchat: 3, timestamp: "2021-05-31T16:05:52.904Z", body: "Test"},
   {id: 1, id_profile: 1, id_groupchat: 3, timestamp: "2021-06-31T16:10:33.662Z", body: "Test2"},
   {id: 1, id_profile: 1, id_groupchat: 3, timestamp: "2021-07-31T15:10:33.662Z", body: "Test3"},
   {id: 1, id_profile: 2, id_groupchat: 3, timestamp: "2021-07-31T16:10:33.662Z", body: "Test4"},
]
```

I have a list and I would like to replace an element in the list and place it again at the same posistion. I have the following three values: `id_profile`, `id_groupchat`, `timestamp`

I now search in the list the object which is equal with the values

```
var id_profile = 1
var id_groupchat = 3
var timestamp = "2021-06-31T16:10:33.662Z"
```

There is only one element in the list, this one which exactly matches the values:

```
{id: 1, id_profile: 1, id_groupchat: 3, timestamp: "2021-06-31T16:10:33.662Z", body: "Test2"},
```

I would now like to replace this with

```
{id: 1, id_profile: 'new', id_groupchat: 3, timestamp: "2021-06-31T16:10:33.662Z", body: "This is a new body"},
```

and put it back into the list

```
[
   {id: 2, id_profile: 2, id_groupchat: 3, timestamp: "2021-05-31T16:05:52.904Z", body: "Test"},
   {id: 1, id_profile: 'new', id_groupchat: 3, timestamp: "2021-06-31T16:10:33.662Z", body: "This is a new body"},
   {id: 1, id_profile: 1, id_groupchat: 3, timestamp: "2021-07-31T15:10:33.662Z", body: "Test3"},
   {id: 1, id_profile: 2, id_groupchat: 3, timestamp: "2021-07-31T16:10:33.662Z", body: "Test4"},
]
```

Now my question, how can I do this?

To set an object, I have always used the following:

```
const incomingMessage = {
        ...message,
        id_profile: message.senderId,
        //id: 'event',
        timestamp: message.timestamp,
        chatid: message.roomid
      };

setMessages((messages) => [...messages.slice(-30), incomingMessage]);
```

How can I now exchange only this one object in the complete list and then exchange the complete list again?

What I tried

```
  // Just the question, so I put it on it.
  // How can I say that an element which has the same values should be removed? 
  const removeMessage = () => {
    var newBody = {body: "This is a new body"};
      const incomingMessage = {
        ...newBody,
        id_profile: 'new',
        timestamp: "2021-06-31T16:10:33.662Z"
        id: 1
        id_groupchat: 3
      };;
      setMessages((messages) => [...messages, incomingMessage]);
    }
```

Comment: _"Now my question, how can I do this?"_ - Don't do it at all - at least not in this particular way... `.find()` the object and just modify it. There's no need to change the content of the array itself.

Comment: How can I edit it once I have found it? Thanks for the hint!

Comment: How do you identify the element you want to update/replace?

Comment: _"How can I edit it..."_ - It's an object, so `object.property = ...` o.O

Comment: @Andreas No, this is React, we don't just mutate objects in state. A copy of the object being updated needs to be made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you identify which specific element in the `messages` state you want to update you can map the previous state to the next state, creating a shallow copy of the array and a shallow copy of the element being updated.

```
setMessages(messages => messages.map(message => /* match condition */ ? {
  ...message,
  id_profile: 'new',
  body: "This is a new body",
  // any other properties being updated
} : message);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! How can I specify these match options for example if I want to say now where the timestamp and the id_profile is the same?

Comment: @user16006564 Something like `message => message.timestamp === timestamp && message.id_profile === id_profile ? ....`?

Comment: Okay, thank you very much! I really appreciate it. :)

Comment: @user16006564 It sounded like you had another question about removing an element, the process is nearly the same, but uses `Array.prototype.filter` instead, i.e. `messages => message.filter(message => message.timestamp !== timestamp && ...other conditions ...)`, the conditions just need to evaluate overall to a boolean value, true for keep, false for remove.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of slice we can just loop through the array using `Array.map` and return the updated object when the condition matches else return the original as it is.

```
var id_profile = 1;
var id_groupchat = 3;
var timestamp = "2021-06-31T16:10:33.662Z";

var updatedMessage = {id: 1, id_profile: 'new', id_groupchat: 3, timestamp: "2021-06-31T16:10:33.662Z", body: "This is a new body"};

setMessages(messages => messages.map(message => {
  if (message.id_profile === id_profile &&
    message.id_groupchat === id_groupchat &&
    message.timestamp === timestamp) {
    return {
      ...message,
      ...updatedMessage
    }
  }
  return message;
}));
```